# "Unable to get the Countif property of the Worksheetfunction class" error

Tags: excel, vba

I get a "Unable to get the Countif property of the Worksheetfunction class" error when using this code

```
    Windows("usertemp.xls").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$18695").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "28", "BE", "CH", "DE", "FR", "JP", "NL"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Dim Impats As Integer
Impats = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AL:AL").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), "I")
MsgBox Impats
```

Comment: #FunFacts: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` isn't a property - that error message is messed-up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CounIf` does not accept a multi-area range. You need to loop over the `Areas`:

```
Dim impats As Long, r As Range
For Each r In Range("AL:AL").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
    impats = impats + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "I")
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`  will create a disjointed range and `Countif` does not play nice with disjointed ranges.

You will need to use a loop to loop through each criteria and add the `Countifs` together.

Try this:

```
Dim arr() as variant
Dim arrPart as variant
arr = Array("28", "BE", "CH", "DE", "FR", "JP", "NL")

Dim Impats As Integer

For Each arrPart in arr
    Impats = Impats + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ActiveSheet.Range("AL:AL"), "I",ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"),arrPart)
Next arrPart
MsgBox Impats
```