# Checking if data exists and adding it if not

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have two rows containing dates which I am trying to compare and see if they are the same. If not, I want to add the extra data (i.e. row 1 can change and so I want those changes added to row 2). Ive tried looking around and also writing my own loop but I`m getting an error.

***UPDATE*** *following the comment, i am still getting an error; "Unable to get the CountIf propety of the worksheetfunction class"*

I am wondering if there are any alternatives to check if the data is present somewhere in the second row add add it if not.
I am new to vba and programming in general and any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim Dates As Range
Set Dates = Range("C23:O23")
Dim hisdate As Range
Set hisdate = Range("C35:O35")

For Each cell In Dates 'this is gonna first add new dates
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(hisdate, cell) > 0 Then 'do nothing
    Else
        Set hisdate = Union(hisdate, cell)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The error probably results from using `hisdates`, when you haven't declared any such variable. Change to `hisdate`.

Comment: Thanks for that, tha'ts a real silly mistake. Still getting errors though

Comment: I guess, this is [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You need to compare dates in two rows and see if they are the same, but all you do in code is just take one date from one row and search for it in another one.

Comment: This macro do nothing. It just sets new value to hisdate variable, that's all.

Comment: Try: `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(....)...`

Comment: @JohnyL why is that? if it finds it, I want to do nothing, if not(else) then I want to add that bit to hisdate

Comment: @ashleedawg, thanks but that doesnt seem to fix it

Comment: Once again: ***and see if they are the same***. This means that same set of dates must be in both rows.

Comment: Your error comes from a range that contains several subranges (called `areas`). The function works correctly until you execute the first `union` statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703316/unable-to-get-the-countif-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class-error

Comment: @FunThomas, but if I use + instead of union I still get an error

Comment: Either you change your logic and for example use a dictionary, or you have to implement a search logic similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703839/7599798

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` doesn't work with *multi-area* ranges. You could write your own countIf-function that loops over all areas (works even if the range is not a multi-area range)

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Dates 'this is gonna first add new dates
    If MyCountIf(hisdate, cell) <= 0 Then
        Set hisdate = Union(hisdate, cell)
    End If
Next
Debug.Print hisdate.Address

Function MyCountIf(fullRange As Range, val As Variant)
    MyCountIf = 0
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In fullRange.Areas
        MyCountIf = MyCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, val)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! This takes away the errors but the macro doesnt seem to be doing anything

Comment: Then I would suggest to Debug the code (use F8) to see where it fails. I did a quick test with some example data and it worked (it added some cells to the range)